# showing warning message while using Php Unit for unit testing in php

Tags: phpunit

When i am trying to make unit testing the each file using PHPUnit tool i am getting the follwing message..........

```
  PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library     
  '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so:
  undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0
  No direct script access allowed.
```

Can any tell me what is the reason for getting this message and how can i solve these problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally in `.ini` files you may have first line starting with '#',actually this is not treated as a comment in `.ini` files.So remove that file or replace '#' with ';'.